# Unable to access location: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out

Tags: networking

The computer that is being accessed runs Ubuntu 20.04 and has a shared Public folder. Importantly, this same computer sees my local network and can access shared folders,etc. on it. I have seen this sort of error before, several times. Oddly enough after days to weeks,this error message stops popping out and all computers on the network become accessible. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps others with this frustrating problem.
On each machine running Ubuntu 16.04 add to the `[Global]` section of the `smb.conf` file located at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, the  following lines:

```
client min protocol = SMB2 
client max protocol = SMB2
```

Most of the computers on my network run Ubuntu 16.04 and the problem was getting the error message

```
Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Connection Timed Out.
```

when connecting to a newer machine running Ubuntu 20.04. The new machine could see the network and connect to any machine on it, but not the other way around, i.e. the older machines running Ubuntu 16.04 could not access the Ubuntu 20.04 machine and responded with

```
Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Connection Timed Out.
```

It would be helpful if an expert explained why this problem occurs and why the Ubuntu/Linux developers have not fixed it. Yes I know, Samba is developed and maintained by another group ...